# Google Spreadsheet adding sheetname

Tags: google-sheets

I have my current query below;

```
=QUERY({Source_1!B2:I;Source_2!B2:I;Source_3!B2:I},"select * where Col3 is not null",0)
```

I want to have all my data be combine to one to "All_Sheet" tab it works so far.

Now I need in Col A of my tab "All_Sheet" be included to all rows the Sheet Name like Source_1, Source_2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Add a calculated column**
First build a range that contains the sheet name you want to reference.  I did it by concatenating a range that is empty and the sheet name:

`{N2:N&"Sheet1",Source_1!B2:I}`

The above by itself won't work, because it needs to be told that it is an array.  So we wrap it in ARRAYFORMULA():

`ARRAYFORMULA({N2:N&"Sheet1",Source_1!B2:I})`
Which gives a range that looks like this:

Then build up the rest of your query like this:
Sheet 1 | B2 Value | C2 Value | D2 Value | ...

**Build our Query**
Take the above and build up your multiple ranges and complete your query. Linebreaks for readability

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    {
     N2:N&"Sheet1",Source_1!B2:I; 
     N2:N&"Sheet2",Source_2!B2:I; 
     N2:N&"Sheet3", Source_3!B2:I
    }),
 "select * where Col3 is not null",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kris, appreciated really. It works as what I've wanted. Thanks again Kris.

Comment: Yes i marked with the check i guess its like that. Thanks Kris